# Remove index.php from URL in code Igniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i have read posts regarding this but that did not gave answer to my problem
i have set everything i found on forums of code igniter and SO's questions

currently i have following settings :
.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    #This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|cache)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 /application/errors/404.php
</IfModule>
```

and i also have set `$config['index_page'] = '';`

but this is not working there is not change in URL 
if i type *http://localhost:8088/crud_demo/index.php/login* it works but if i type *http://localhost:8088/crud_demo/login* it shows Not Found Error

My Route config

```
$route['register'] = "register";
$route['manage'] = "manage";
$route['default_controller'] = "login";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: Did you restart your apache instance after doing the htaccess changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^crud_demo/(.*)$ crud_demo/index.php/$1`

http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ to test URL rewrites.

I think CodeIgniter has it's own way of routing URLs like other PHP frameworks.  Take a look here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: i think my .htaccess is not applying

Comment: I think there should be a `route.php` file inside the config folder.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All in my virtual host file at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` in ubuntu

Change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All in my virtual host file at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf` in windows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All    <---- replace None with All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All   <---  replace None with All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
....
```

Then put this code in .htaccess file in root folder in codeigniter

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

It will definately work.

Comment: Thanks I will be always there to help

Answer (score 0):

If crud_demo is a subfolder of your root dir then you should change

`RewriteBase /`

to

`RewriteBase /crud_demo`

Comment: directory is C:/wamp/www/crud_demo

Comment: Yeah the base needs changing, try it